# Angular Error: Error: Could not find column with id when it's in TS

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my app, I have a table with multiple columns. I'm trying to fill it with the respected data but when the page opens I get the error `Could not find column with id "PublishedParty"` yet, it's in the TS file. Here is my code, what is wrong with it?

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isPublishedParty == true" matColumnDef="PublishedParty">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="min-width: 100px !important;" [ngStyle]="{'color': 'black'}" style="text-align: center;">
      <b>
        Planlanan Miktar
      </b>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index" style="min-width: 100px !important;" style="text-align: center;">
      <div>
        Miktar: {{row.PublishedPartyQuantity | number}}
      </div>
      <div>
        Parti: {{row.PublishedPartyCount | number}}
      </div>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

TS:

```
isPublishedParty = false;
private _materialPlan: IMaterialPlan = {};
@Input() 
set MaterialPlan(prm: IMaterialPlan){
  this._materialPlan = prm;
}

get MaterialPlan(): IMaterialPlan {
  return this._materialPlan;
}
displayedColumns: string[] = [
  'StockIntegrationCode',
  'ReceiptName',
  'PublishedParty',
];

dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IMaterialPlanReceiptResult>;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;


constructor(
) {
  if(this._materialPlan.IncludePlannedParty == true){
    this.isPublishedParty == true;
  }
}
```

Comment: `it's in the TS file` It can't be, since a column with id "PublishedParty" is expected to be in the HTML code, not Typescript. Not sure what part of the code exactly is expecting to find an element with an ID in an Angular application, though

Comment: I mean it's in `displayedColumns` as well. Yet, it can't find that element. @JeremyThille

Comment: Is this._materialPlan.IncludePlannedParty set to true? And what happends, when you let it be true? Maybe you have to remove the ColumnName from the displayedColumns, when the condition for this._materialPlan.IncludePlannedParty is not true.

Comment: I'm trying to display the PlannedParty column when it is set to true. But right now, it is not. How can I remove the ColumnName when it's false? @KevinGlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the problem is, that you hide the ng-container when the condition in your constructor is false for "this._materialPlan.IncludePlannedParty".

So the solution could be, to remove the column name from the displayColumns array:

```
private _materialPlan: IMaterialPlan = {};
@Input()
set MaterialPlan(prm: IMaterialPlan){
    this._materialPlan = prm;
}

get MaterialPlan(): IMaterialPlan {
    return this._materialPlan;
}
displayedColumns: string[] = [];

dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IMaterialPlanReceiptResult>;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;


constructor(
) {
    this.displayedColumns = [
        'StockIntegrationCode',
        'ReceiptName',
    ];
    if(this._materialPlan.IncludePlannedParty == true){
        this.isPublishedParty == true;
        this.displayedColumns.push('PublishedParty');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but now all the columns have disappeared. Even the ones that were set to `true`

Comment: You could try the solution of Joosep.P. If that doesn't help, you could try to move the code in my example from the constructor to the setter of MaterialPlan (at the beginning)

Comment: Okay thabk you, when I moved it to the setter it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For angular to render the table correctly `isPublishedParty` should be initialized as true. Otherwise *ngIf removes it from the template and you would get such an error. You could set `isPublishedParty` to false at later time, perhaps in `ngAfterViewInit()` cycle.